# Accessing other functions after running one with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's my code

```
# Start of functions
# The menu is called exclusively from the main program code
def menu():
    print "Please choose an option."
    print "1 = User name"
    print "2 = Factorial"
    print "3 = Quit"
    choice=int(raw_input(":"))

    # Stars to validate options
    while choice <1 or choice >3 :
        print "Invalid menu choice"
        print "Please choose an option."
        print "1 = User name"
        print "2 = Factorial"
        print "3 = Quit"
        choice=int(raw_input(":"))
    else:
        return choice

def get_initial(name):
    # Will remove all letters after the first one in name to get initial
    name=name[:1]
    return name

def get_last_name(name):
    # -1 counts backwards from the end of string and splits off first word
    name = str(name.split()[-1])
    return name

# Function will produce and give username based off of the full name that was input
def print_username():
    full_name = str(raw_input("What is your name?: "))
    initial = get_initial(full_name)
    last_name = get_last_name(full_name)
    username = str(initial) + str(last_name)
    # Converts 'username' to lowercase and stores
    username = username.lower()
    print username
    print menu()

# Takes factorial and multiplies it by the number the preceeds it down to 0
def print_factorial():
    number = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
    factorial = 1
    counter = number
    while counter > 0:
        factorial=factorial*counter
        print counter,
        if counter > 1:
            print'*',
        counter=counter-1
    print '=', factorial
    print menu()


# Start of main program
# Result of menu used to create global variable
choice = menu()

while choice != 3:
    if choice == 1:
        print print_username()
    elif choice == 2:
        print print_factorial()
    else:
        choice = menu()
        break
```

My problem is once I do factorials or username I need it to allow me to access the menu and either access and carry out the username, factorial or exit function. It doesn't do that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print_username` and `print_factorial` functions are only ever *printing* the `menu()` return value. They are not doing anything with these. In your top-level `while` loop you only ever call `menu()` again if the *existing* `choice` is neither 1 nor 2, but your `while` loop exits if `3` was picked before.

Instead, call `menu` every single time through your `while` loop:

```
# Start of main program
# Result of menu used to create global variable
while True:
    choice = menu()
    if choice == 1:
        print_username()
    elif choice == 2:
        print_factorial()
    else:
        break
```

and remove the `print menu()` lines from your `print_username()` and `print_factorial()` functions.

The above loop is endless (`while True:`), but if `menu()` returned anything other than `1` or `2` then the `break` statement would be reached and the loop is exited. At that point your program ends too.